# Как отформатировать дату, пришедшую в ответе от сервера?

Tags: android, яндекс-погода

Работаю с Api Yandex-Погоды. В поле String date в ответе от сервера приходит дата прогноза погоды в формате 26/03/2020. Методом `getDate()` извлекаю её. Как её отформатировать, чтобы вместо даты в формате день/месяц/год, на экране показывались дни недели (среда, четверг...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать таким способом:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourdate); // yourdate должно быть типом Date

int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал, сработало!)